# Return values and constraints for asm (assembler code) using gnu Extended Asm

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

As a (beginners) exercise I want to implement a swap operation in C using GNU asm.

I'm confused about the restraints. My code is:

```
    int c = 1;
    int b = 2;
    asm ("xchg %2,%3"
            : "=r" (c), "=r" (b)
            : "<X>" (c), "<Y>" (b)
            );
    return c+10*b;
```

Where $<X>$ and $<Y>$ are replaced by ("0", "0"), ("0", "r"), ("r", "r") and ("r", 0").

("0", "0") does not compile. (Why?)

("0", "r") returns 12, the expected result.

("r", "r") and ("r", "0") return 21, as if nothing happened. (Why?)

So what is wrong in those cases? Why does it fail?

Comment: 0,0 makes no sense, you can't put two operands in the same place. With `r` the compiler may choose whatever register it wants and since you never reference 0 or 1 in the asm block there is no telling where the result is. That 0,r happens to work is just an accident, it's still wrong. The correct constraint is 1,0.

Comment: @Jester "0,1" works, "1,0" doesn't. It looks like my main misunderstanding was to look at "0" as some fixed keyword, not as a reference to "%0", is that correct? If so, please make it an answer (perhaps with some more explanation for others that come here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `: "+r" (c), "+r" (b)` to declare read/write operands<sup>1</sup> (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html) In/out instructions go in the first (output) group of constraints.

And of course you should use `xchg %0, %1` to make sure the asm template only references operands you actually declared.

```
asm ("xchg %0,%1"
            : "+r" (c), "+r" (b)
  );
```

Footnote 1:  Fun fact: GCC internally implements read/write operand by inventing matching input constraints for these output.  So if you didn't fix the `%2,%3` in the template, it would still compile.  But you wouldn't have any guarantee of which order GCC chose to do the matching constraints in.

---

To find out what happened with your wrong constraints, make your asm template print the unused operand names as an asm comment, e.g. `xchg %2,%3  # inputs= %0,%1` so you can look at the compiler's *asm* output (`gcc -S` or on https://godbolt.org), and see which registers it picked.  If it picked opposite constraints you'd see no swap.

Or with `"r"` if it picked 2 registers that are different from the output operands then you're stepping on the compilers toes by modifying registers it expected to remain unchanged (because you told it those were inputs, and could be in separate registers from the outputs.)  So no, `"r"` can't be safe.

---

If you did want to use matching constraints manually, you'd of course use `"0"(c), "1"(b)` to force it to pick the same register for `c` as an input that it picked for `c` as the output #0, and same for `b` as input as output #1.

**Of course there's no need for a runtime instruction at all to just tell the compiler that C variables have each other's values.**

```
asm ("nop  # c input in %2, output in %0.  b input in %3, output in %1"
     :  "=r" (c), "=r" (b)
     :  "1"(c),   "0"  (b)   // opposite matching constraints
  );
```

Even the `nop` is unnecessary, but https://godbolt.org/ by default filters comments so it's convenient to put a comment on a NOP.

Comment: So, if the output variables are declared "+r" I don't need to repeat them as input variables? It works in a first test, but I'm not sure if that is but by accident.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: Yes, check the manual, that's the entire point of `+`.   https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Modifiers.html

Comment: Thanks, but "Means that this operand is both read and written by the instruction. " could also be interpreted way that *that  register* is r/w. I think this is the difference between newcomers and experienced users.

Comment: @GyroGearloose: Well yeah, the compiler picks a register, your asm template reads and writes it.  If you read before writing, the value is the value the C variable had before the asm statement.  (Unlike an `"=r"` output, which is assumed to be write only as far as connecting it up to the values of C variables, like doing `var = ...`.  You already seem to know this since you know you needed input constraints.  `"+r"` makes it like doing `var += ...` or `var -= ...`, an RMW).  If you use `"=r"(foo)`, you can still read that register in your asm template *after* you've written a value to it.

Comment: and +1 for the nop-version :-)